# Using the curve() function to show changes in a logistic curve

Tags: r, curve

I have a question asking to use `curve()`or `geom_function()` to show how the logistic curve changes as each parameter (`a` and `b`) varies from positive to negative.

They gave a logistic curve of:
y = (exp(a + bx)/1 + exp(a + bx)

Within the `curve()` function I can see where to put the expression but it is not recognizing when I put this equation in.

```
curve(expr, from = NULL, to = NULL, n = 101, add = FALSE,
  type = "l", xname = "x", xlab = xname, ylab = NULL,
  log = NULL, xlim = NULL, …)
```

I have tried:
`curve(expr = (exp(a + bx)/1 + exp(a + bx)), from = -10, to = 10, n = 10)`

where I made up numbers for the range and the n. But it does not recognize it as a function or expression. I have to somehow be able to make two plots, one where a varies, and one where b varies over a number of values.

Does anyone know how to input the expression into the formula and then manipulate the variables?

Comment: The expression must be valid R syntax. You cannot omit `*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must separate `*` and `/` properly. Define curve as `lg` and then by loop, draw curve.

```
lg <- function(x, a = 1, b = 1){
  exp(a+b*x) / (1+exp(a+b*x))
}
# curves with changing b
for (b in c(1:5)){
  curve(expr = lg(x, 1, b), from = -5, to = 5, n = 100, add= TRUE, col = b)
}
```

[image: b]

```
# curves with changing a
for (a in c(1:5)){
  curve(expr = lg(x, a, 1), from = -5, to = 5, n = 100, add= TRUE, col = a)
}
```

[image: a]

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful! I had created my own function but it was only giving me one line when I plotted. I think I defined a and b incorrectly. I also have never used loops before so I think that will come in handy in the future.

Comment: Do you know what I can do in Rmarkdown to knit this document? When I run it as separate chunks, I get the error:
error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x y) type = type ...) plot.new has not been called yet  Calls: <Anonymous> ... eval -> curve -> lines -> lines.default -> plot.xy

Comment: @AlisonMeeth I'm sorry that I'm not familiar  with R markdown...